# Refresh ListView from another activity

Tags: android

I have two activities: "A" (my main activity with a ListView) and "B" (is a form showed as dialog). When I start "B" from "A", I need "A" is not finished but stay in background. Then, when I finish "B" I need the ListView in "A" refreshes its items. How can I do? Let me know if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Using OnActiivtyForResult in android

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult` and then refresh your Listview using `notifyDataSetChanged`  (or `restartLoader` if you are using loaders) after adding your new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch B activity with `startActivityForResult` and catch the result in `onActivityResult`.
Remember to use a unique code for Activity B when launched so you can check if the response is the right one.

**Example**

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {

    if(requestCode == 100&&resultCode=RESULT_OK) 
     {
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```